# Understanding empty \newcommand's in etoolbox.sty

Tags: etoolbox

In `etoolbox.sty`, three commands `\ifdefmacro`, `\ifdefparam` and `\ifdefprotected` are firstly defined by `\newcommand\cmd{}`, then by `\long\edef\cmd{...}`. I don't understand why the empty `\newcommand`s are there.

One reason I can think of is that `\newcommand\cmd` checks if `\cmd` is definable, hence raises error if `\cmd` is already defined when loading `etoolbox`. Then, is there some other popular package that provides the same three commands in the history? On the other hand, why these three (and only three) commands are special?

Update: As indicated by @moewe's answer, there are six such commands in total, the other three are firstly defined by `\newcommand*\cmd{}`. You can use a regular expression like `\\newcommand\*?\{\\[a-zA-Z]+\}{}` to match all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`etoolbox` uses `\newcommand` or `\newrobustcmd` for *all* user-level commands (to avoid name clashes I presume). Some commands get empty initial definitions with `\newcommand{\<cmd>}{}` because their real definition needs an `\edef` or some other treatment that `\newcommand` doesn't provide. E.g.

`\newrobustcmd` gets an empty initial definition because it needs to be defined `\protected\def`

```
\newcommand*{\newrobustcmd}{}
\protected\def\newrobustcmd{\@star@or@long\etb@new@command}
```

and `\ifdefmacro` is ultimately defined via an `\edef`

```
\newcommand{\ifdefmacro}{}
\long\edef\ifdefmacro#1{%
  \noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\etb@ifdefmacro
  \noexpand\meaning#1\detokenize{macro}:&}
\edef\etb@ifdefmacro{%
  \def\noexpand\etb@ifdefmacro##1\detokenize{macro}:##2&}
\etb@ifdefmacro{\notblank{#2}}
```

`\protecting` needs a `#{` type 'argument' (for lack of a better term)

```
\newcommand*{\protecting}{}
\def\protecting#{%
  \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
    \etb@protecting\@firstofone
  \fi
  \ifx\protect\@unexpandable@protect
    \etb@protecting\etb@unexpandable
  \fi
  \ifx\protect\noexpand
    \etb@protecting\unexpanded
  \fi
  \ifx\protect\string
    \etb@protecting\detokenize
  \fi
  \relax\@firstofone}

\def\etb@protecting#1#2\relax\@firstofone{\fi#1}
\long\def\etb@unexpandable#1{\unexpanded{\protecting{#1}}}
```

but many other macros like `\ifcsmacro` use a `\newcommand` directly

```
\newcommand*{\ifcsmacro}[1]{%
  \ifcsdef{#1}
    {\expandafter\ifdefmacro\csname#1\endcsname}
    {\@secondoftwo}}
```

---

Internal commands (`\etb@...`) are usually defined directly with `\def`/`\edef`/... and not via `\newcommand`, because name clashes are not expected there.

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't catch those empty `\newcommand` all. So, this is for consistently checking naming clash taken by `\newcommand` (which is equivalent to `\ifcsname` in the current implementation)?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ That's what I suspect, yes. (Of course I can't be sure why the package author really wrote things that way, but I think it's a fair assumption.)

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Sorry, I only just saw the comment about `\ifcsname`. I don't quite understand what you mean there. Can you clarify what you meant, please?

Comment: In the current implementation of `\newcommand`, it uses `\@ifdefinable`, which uses `\@ifundefined`, which uses `\ifcsname` to check name clash. So to check name clash, using `\newcommand` is the same as directly using `\ifcsname` but with better error message.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ no `\ifcsname` is true if the csname has a definition so after `\let\foo` it is true for `foo` but the latex definition treats relax as undefined and also gives errors for any command that stars with `end` whether it is defined or not.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. Follow your comment, I have just read the definition of `\@ifdefinable` and saw the logic you said.